# C# DataGridView Text Style?

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image: datagridview]

See my datagridview.

First record was added via HeidiSQL.
Second was added via DataGridView on C# Winform.

I just want the first record style.
Can anyone tell me what makes second style and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some code, to clarify how and what you are doing.

Comment: I think code doesn't matter because DataTable and DataSource settings are all. I think it's kind of matter character set like UTF8. And I'm working on it.